# Webpack load different modules based on chunk

Tags: javascript, webpack, node-modules

Is it possible to make webpack load another module based on some context information?

For example I've two versions of my React application: desktop and mobile

In my index.js I decide which application to load:

```
if (isMobile()) {
   loadMobile().then(({default: App}) => render(App))
}
```

Now I would like to reuse some modules, but some I would like to override it. So by default it should load index.js, but if the context `isMobile` and next to the `index.js` a `mobile.js` file exists, it should load the `mobile` variant.

```
components/
  Button/
    index.js
    mobile.js
```

*In the mobile context, webpack should load mobile.js instead of index.js*

I could't find anything that I could use to solve it, any ideas?

---

PS: I've already created an issue on github, it also demonstrates the problem and what I want to achieve even better:

https://github.com/webpack/enhanced-resolve/issues/180

Answer (score 5):

You can use dynamic loading function and dynamic importing syntax for this problem.

1. Install Babel plugin `plugin-syntax-dynamic-import`:

   ```
   npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import
   ```

   and use it in `.babelrc`

   ```
   {
     "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import"]
   }
   ```
2. You need to create a component called `load` with the following
   codes:

   ```
       export default const load = (platform="index") => componentName => 
       import(`components/${componentName}/${platform}.js`);
   ```
3. Then use dynamic import with loading function like the following
   code:

   ```
       const { Button } = await import("components/Loader.jsx").then(load => {
         load(${platform})(${componentName})
       })
   ```

These articles may help you:

- https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/webpack-and-dynamic-imports-doing-it-right-72549ff49234
- https://blog.jscrambler.com/how-to-make-your-app-faster-with-webpack-dynamic-imports/
- https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports

Comment: Thank you for your effort of writing it down, but it does not answer my original question. The problem with this approach is that all of the modules are loaded dynamically, so you have to use Promises. 

My original question is already using the dynamic loading approach, I am just looking for a way to include the mobile.js files instead of index.js into the  `mobile.bundle.js` and the default (index.js) files into the `desktop.bundle.js`

Comment: Okay, what about this article: https://remarkablemark.org/blog/2017/02/25/webpack-ignore-module/ . This one may solve that problem. You will have 2 builds and on each of them, you will able to erase unnecessary one.

Comment: Thats exactly what I wand to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different ways you can achieve this.

1. Create 2 entry points 1 each for mobile and desktop so that webpack generate 2 bundles. You can load only the desired bundle from the html.
2. If you `require/import` the Mobile code inside `loadMobile()` webpack automatically splits the code into 2 bundles. The mobile bundle is loaded only if it is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you have to create two builds: one with default [resolve.mainFiles](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvemainfiles) and one with

```
resolve: {
    mainFiles: ['mobile', 'index']
}
```

You will need to decide which bundle to load inside your html. Or create two different html files and move `isMobile` logic to the webserver config so it'll decide which html to return to user.

Some chunks might be the same between both builds. But it is very likely that you will end up with two different apps. You might reduce the built code duplication between two apps with [DllPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/dll-plugin/).